# grunt-protractor-runner Option.args mochaOpts

Tags: grunt-plugins

I am having hard time with passing arguments to the `grunt-protractor-runner` plug-in. I am trying to tag some of my tests and then call that specific test. So, my command for running test's is:

```
grunt e2e:cert:ed:regression_part_3
```

But, what I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
grunt protractor --mochaOpts={tags:"myTag"} e2e:cert:ed:regression_part_3
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Error message ?

Comment: @ perror 
it just doesn't work , like it skips this commands, no error message... the process continues to run one other grunt task after the "e2e".  so the first one is:  protractor:e2e and the second one is: protractor:continuous in that order in my config.

Comment: @perror this is the part of my config file:  e2e: {
         options: {
        keepAlive: false,
        noColor: false,
  }
 },
 continuous: {
  options: {
         keepAlive: true
  }
 }